# Core Service 2011 - Address books

Tags: tridion

Is it possible to create Audience Manager Address Books using the Core Service (Tridion 2011 SP1)?

(Or automate creating them in any other way - db script, Interop?)

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no Audience Manager functionality in the Core Service; only Content Manager functionality is exposed there.

You can, however, use the public API (Tridion.AudienceManagement.API) on the server to create any item you want. You didn't specify the kind of Address Book you want to create - but I'm going to assume you want a static one to create Contacts in.

Here is some sample code to do that:

```cs
StaticAddressBook denmark = new StaticAddressBook();
denmark.Title = "Denmark";
denmark.Key = "DK";
denmark.Save();
```

If you want to create a Dynamic Address Book instead, you'll need to specify a filter too; let me know if that's the case and I can provide some sample code for that too.

Comment: FYI, you need to be a Tridion Administrator to create Address Books.

Comment: Thanks Peter. See my comment below - I've referenced the DLL but get type initializor errors. I dont think I've setup my VS solution correctly, I'm working on the CM server directly but not sure what I need to do to get this working.

Comment: Got this working eventually - had to add a config key called "Configuration" to point to my OutboundEmail.xml and ensure that the user running the console was granted access to the TridionRsaKeyContainer encryption key as the database part of OutboundEmail.xml was encrypted. After that it worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Tridion.OutboundEmail.ContentManagement namespace. In there is an AddressBook object (or you can use StaticAddressBook depending on the type of AB you want to create). Something like this should work:

```
AddressBook ab = new AddressBook();
ab.Title = "The title of my new Address Book";
ab.Save();
```

Looking at the API for StaticAddressBook (it's documented) there's a static method StaticAddressBook.CreateLocalAddressBook that might actually be more relevant in this instance. I'd check it out if I were you ;)  You can download the docs from SDLTridionWorld.com

Comment: Tridion.OutboundEmail.ContentManagement is the old, deprecated API. You should use Tridion.AudienceManagement.API instead.

Also, local Address Books are meant for temporary purposes and can be created by users with fewer rights; they are automatically assigned to the given Publication and everyone has full access to it. I would not use that for any other purpose than importing lists of Contacts you get from a 3rd party and need to use for a single campaign and then delete afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. AddressBook is an abstract class in Tridion.AudienceManagement.API - which I think is the public API on AM - so cant be instantiated like that. Is there anything specail I need to to work with this DLL? I've created a small console app, reference the Tridion.AudienceManagement.API dll but when run on the CM machine I get a type initialization error - Loading of configuration failed.