# Get the Session for the currently logged in User - Custom Pages

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am trying to develop a Custom Page, wherein, I am trying to get a List of all Components that are present in a particular publication.

In the Page Load of the aspx page, I need to get the session for the currently logged in     User.

When I try to use the code

```
    Session currSession = new Session();
    Response.Write(currSession.User.Id);
```

I get the following error.

```
Access is denied for the user NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
```

When I try the code with

```
Session currSession = new Session(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
Response.Write(currSession.User.Id);
```

I get the following error.

```
The name 'WindowsIdentity' does not exist in the current context
```

1.) What should be a proper method to get the session in a Custom Page ?
Can we use the HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables.Get("REMOTE_USER"), to get the user.

2.) Should Custom Page use CoreServices or TOM.NET API's to get information from CM. Which is the preferred option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the TOM.NET API for processes other than Templates and Event System. Please use the Core Service API instead for this (there you won't need a Session).

I might rephrase this to: you **should not** use the TOM.NET API for processes other than Templates and Event System. As technically it is possible, but it's not supposed to be used like that, that is what the core service is introduced for.

Comment: The exception being Audience Manager/Address Books as the Core Service doesn't expose any AM functionality - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962162/core-service-2011-address-books.

Comment: And if you're running "inside" the Tridion website, you can use the following to get the current user: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Comment: Tridion.AudienceManagement.API is not part of the TOM.NET, that one you are allowed to use in custom pages etc. you don't need a Session in there.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Windows Authentication, you can use this snippet to view the current user and the roles attached in your .aspx:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Security" %>  
<% 
string[] rolesArray = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
Response.Write("<strong>LoggedIn User = </strong>" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + "<br />");
Response.Write("<strong>Roles LoggedIn User = </strong><br />" + string.Join(",<br />", rolesArray));
%>
```

Maybe you need to add this to the web.config of your custom page:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
```

Hope this helps,
Guus